# INSERT and DELETE in the same transaction?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have a Temp_Table with some data. Based on the data in the Temp_Table, I will delete the related rows from other tables, and after that, insert all data from the Temp-table to table1. Like the example below.

**In what way could I place a lock on Server2.Table1 (exclusive I supose) and run both the Delete and Insert statements before letting go of that lock?** I don't want anyone to read or write to Table1 while I am doing my Delete / Inserts. Note that the Delete must be run **before** the Insert statement.

Is there a way is SSIS to do this? Or can I use Begin transaction in the beginning and commit transaction after the statements? I fear that both the Delete and Insert will run simultaneously while in the same transaction..

```
DELETE Table1 
FROM Table1 t1
    INNER JOIN (    
       SELECT Column2 FROM Temp_Table
       GROUP BY Column2
    ) t2 ON t1.Column2 = t2.Column2

INSERT INTO Table1
SELECT (Column1, Column2...)
FROM Temp_Table
```

Comment: Putting these statements between a BEGIN TRANSACTION ... COMMIT does not run them quite simultaneously (they will be committed/rolled back together though). Depending on your isolation level, any locks acquired will remain in place until the transaction is completed or rolled back

Comment: Let's start by asking what exactly you are trying to accomplish.  You are deleting all rows from your table that are related to your temp table and then inserting your temp table result.  Are you really trying to do an UPDATE if rows exist and insert if they don't?  you can use your temp table to track what records to modify so that a lock wont matter, or you can use output as suggested below, or???

Comment: I should add that if you really need to get a lock on the entire table, you can throw this before your delete: SELECT 1 FROM Table1 WITH (TABLOCKX)

Comment: Any reason why you're not using the built-in [replication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx) features?

Comment: Is the objective simply to replicate a table between databases? You're over complicating it. If you have an ID you can use to match between them then there are numerous methods (including `MERGE`, which _can_ be used to insert new rows) to do this. If you want the delete/insert to appear as a single change to a user then quite simply use `BEGIN TRAN` and `COMMIT TRAN` around it

Comment: Other good points are also made: You can use built replication to do this - no need to custom build replication in SSIS

Comment: I need to use SSIS on this, it's part of a larger SSIS solution, but I will have a look at the built in replication. I do have a ID to match on, but I am not sure how to use merge on this. Since only the new rows from today are loaded into temp_table, I don't know what rows are deleted on server1. Is it possible to merge Temp_Table with only these rows from Table1 that are in relationship with the Temp_Table?

Comment: Is it possible ? Yes. You should probably ask a new question though. You should also investigate `MERGE` in detail (although it doesn't do anything that three seperate `DELETE`, `UPDATE`, `INSERT` can't do)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SteveRs comment was correct, **the Insert and Delete statements within a transaction didn't run simultaneously**. After some testing on a non-production database, I ended up with the following:

```
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRAN T1;

DELETE Table1 
FROM Table1 t1
    INNER JOIN (    
       SELECT Column2 FROM Temp_Table
       GROUP BY Column2
    ) t2 ON t1.Column2 = t2.Column2

INSERT INTO Table1 (Column 1, Column2...)
SELECT (Column1, Column2...)
FROM Temp_Table

COMMIT TRAN T1;

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRAN T1;
END CATCH
```

The Delete statement is executed first, then the Insert statement. And the Exclusive lock will not be released between the statements.

Answer (score 2):

You can use OUTPUT clause in delete to insert into temp table

```
DELETE FROM dbo.table1  
OUTPUT DELETED.* INTO @MyTable  --or temp table   
WHERE id = 10
```

In this case both operation will be in single transaction..

Answer (score 0):

A merge statememt will work also.

With a merge you can combine all operations in a single query, which are insert, update and delete.
The operation is based on a comparison between two tables and conditions
The choose to update first then insert.

Answer (score -6):

I'm not the best at SQL but you could remove INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE privileges from other users until you're done.

```
REVOKE INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON Table1 FROM [username]
```

There is probably a much better way.

You could also put the insert on a trigger on delete, but that wont quite guarantee no other transactions will get in there though.